# How to match any digits in front of a certain character?

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to match all digits that are in front of the character `K` and extract that value.

In the example `CARRY18K` it would match the `18`.

Probably I can only achive this with regex, but how?
Is `\d+K` the right expression here?

Comment: You could use: `(\d+)K`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `I'd like to match all digits that are in front of the character K and extract that value.`

You should use:

```
\d+(?=K)
```

`(?=K)` is positive lookahead that makes sure that digits are followed by `K`

Comment: Is the lookahead better than just `\d+K`? If so, why?

Comment: @Cruncher: Good question. Answer is that OP wants to extract the numbers and lookahead saves extra steps of grouping the numbers and capturing `$1` from it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use something like this:

```
\d+K
```

If you want to capture the digits:

```
(\d+)K
```